# PHP Fatal error: Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions' not found when running a sample test in Laravel Plugin

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I'm developping a package for Laravel 5.3+ ( My tests where developped in Laravel 5.3)

I have installed Laravel 5.4, downloaded laravel/browser-kit-testing, and follow upgrade guide.

Now, when I run my tests, I get :

> PHP Fatal error:  Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions' not found

I don't really understand why, because file exists.

In my BrowserKitTestCase.php, I have a reference to

```
$app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

But as I am in my package development folder, I don't think app.php exists, it might be the issue, but can't find out how to fix it...

I tried to change it to:

```
$app = require __DIR__.'/../../../../bootstrap/app.php';
```

where app can be found ( I am in /package/author/plugin/tests/ ) but it error remains the same...

Any idea what's happening???

Comment: Try hardcoding the full path, find out the exact relative path from where your unit tests are running. Echo out `__DIR__` if you need to.

Comment: I already did that, but it is not solving my issue :(

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: I was using orchestra test bench and needed to update the requirement in the `composer.json` when I updated to 5.4